# Polynomial exponential integration

Tags: integration

Through my research I faced the below integral, please help me solving it

$$ \frac{\exp\left(-\frac N2\right)}{2\pi N} \iint \exp\left(-\left( \frac {x^2-2xy-2Ny+2y^2}{2N}\right)\right) \,dx\,dy  $$

Note that $N>0$

Your help is highly appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the integral
$$\iint \exp\left(-\left( \frac {x^2-2xy-2Ny+2y^2}{2N}\right)\right) \,dx\,dy
$$
can be reduced to
$$\iint \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2N}\right)\exp\left(\frac{xy}{N}\right)\exp\left(y\right)\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{N}\right) \,dx\,dy$$

The integral $\int e^{-x^2}\, dx$ is the [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), so your integral cannot be evaluated with elementary functions. Thus I would recommend using a numerical method of finding a definite integral, or use the series expansion of
$$e^x=\sum \frac{1}{n!}x^n$$
with integration by parts
$$\int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du$$
to find the solution to this integral.

Comment: Would you please help me getting the non-elementary solution to the integral       
We may use this results [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514921/exponential-integration-involving-polynomial/1515282#1515282)

Comment: Unfortunately, I lack the required knowledge to provide a solution using the error function. However, you can still use integration by parts along with the error function to evaluate this integral.